# How to install lwib node package for resizing and cropping images?

Tags: node.js, lwip, resize-image

I have tried many times to install [lwip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lwip#write-to-file).
But I can't install that.
I am on windows 10 *64.
I get this err:
Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.

I want a package that I can resize and crop images with that.
I don't want it to be complicated, for example want me to install imageMagick or many others, I want just a package like express.
If you know any, would you tell me them?

Answer (score 0):

did you follow these [Instructions](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation)  ?

Comment: Of course! here's what I did: run 'npm install -g node-gyp' in my node js command prompt, then run 'npm install --global --production windows-build-tools ' in my node js command prompt. But I cannot pass level 2 successfully. When I run 'npm install --global --production windows-build-tools ' I get an error.

Comment: no I ment the pythons stuff. Are you really able to see python version 2.7. and did a "npm config set python python2.7" ?